# Salesforce SOQL and database/record inline edit standalone Application for PC

Tags: soql, ide, tls, query-editor

I'm a longtime Mac user who fell in love with the SOQLExplorer's capability to run a query, double click a field on a returned record, modify the value, and thus update the record in Salesforce.

However I recently changed jobs which exclusively uses Windows (no admin privileges).

I have downloaded a standalone version of FuseIT.SFDC.Explorer which does have this capability and it works pretty well for the most part. However the only version I could find that doesn't require admin rights and has this capability is 3.4.16350.1 and it is using TLS 1.0. I'm assuming that when Salesforce shuts down that protocol March 2017, I'll have to find another solution.

Comment: Have you considered using the query tab in the Developer Console?

Comment: I try to avoid the query tab from Dev Console as I have had poor experiences in the past with that tool. SOQLed data via Salesforce doesn't always appear to return 100% correctly. I find myself closing out of the Dev Console and opening it back up all too often, hence me looking for another tool... :(

Comment: If FuseIT.SFDC.Explorer is the one you want to stick with then you could try to get in touch with its author Daniel Ballinger, e.g. via his blog: http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/12/fuseit-sfdc-explorer-34163492.html, he may be able to take admin privileges issue into account in the next release.

Comment: @rmarq423 Interesting. What can you provide some specific details about what isn't working without admin rights if the FuseIT SFDC Explorer?
I use it in all sorts of orgs, some of which I don't have very high access levels. Is there a specific error you are getting?

Comment: @DanielBallinger I just can't install it on my machine.

Comment: @rmarq423 Are you using the .exe installer or the zip file with the single executable? I've had a few people report false positives from virus scanners, such as avira, I'll need to go through a process to get white listed for it.

Comment: @DanielBallinger let me try on Monday and get back to you. If I recall correctly, it just failed on install - no problems with false positives for viruses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DanielBallinger No problem installing it today. The email was blocked by our firewall, but I was able to forward the url with the zip and successfully query via TLS 1.2 Thanks so much for your suggestions.